# Webpack Babel Function("r", "regeneratorRuntime = r")(r) violates unsafe-eval CSP

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am using the webpack configurations below to build all my JS files:

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

module.exports = {
  entry: Object.fromEntries(glob.sync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js/profile/*.js')).map((v) => [
    path.basename(v, '.js'), v,
  ])),
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/js/profile'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            plugins: [
              [
                "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                {
                  "useESModules": true
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

If I load the appropriate page, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'".
```

When I click on all the unsafe-eval errors, they all point to of the corresponding file:

```
            }(e.exports);
            try {
                regeneratorRuntime = t
            } catch (e) {
                Function("r", "regeneratorRuntime = r")(t)
            }
```

The error is at line `Function("r", "regeneratorRuntime = r")(t)`

In the JS files that are experiencing the errors, I am using `import, export`, `async await` and `arrow functions`.

I have done some research, and it says it is due to the new JS methods introduced that Babel cannot recognize. But I am using the latest Babel and Webpack:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "grunt": "^1.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^5.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.10.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: No, I ended up not using Babel anymore, since my web app does not have a lot of users.

Comment: I decided to replace 'Function("r","regeneratorRuntime = r")(t)' with 'throw e' for modern browser.

Comment: If you do that for every occurrence, is Babel and Webpack working fine?

Comment: I'm using rollup and yes it works fine.